# Session.SessionID does it stay the same after timeout?

Tags: asp.net, session, forms-authentication

I have an asp.net webpage using forms authentication, I have my `SessionState.timeout="4"` and my `FormsAuthentication.timeout="20"` in my web.config file.

So after 4 minutes of inactivity, my session expires but I'm not forced to log back in because the forms authentication is set to longer, but I noticed that the Session.SessionID is still the same after the Session has expired.

Can anyone tell me if this is by design, ie the session is just re-instated?

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx):

> Session identifiers for abandoned or expired sessions are recycled by default. That is, if a request is made that includes the session identifier for an expired or abandoned session, a new session is started using the same session identifier. You can disable this by setting `regenerateExpiredSessionId` attribute of the configuration element to true.

Comment: I was actually hoping to use the fact the sessionid stays the same, for tracking users coming and going.  So if this is by-design then that is going to help me big time.

Comment: Keep in mind the cookie is short-lived. I would recommend using a different cookie that is more long-lived if you want to do long-term tracking.